# Vector error , cannot get push_back to work

Tags: c++, stl, vector, push-back

This is just a snippet of the uncommented code. The packing vector keeps causing an error at the `push_back()`, and I'm not quite sure why:

**EDIT:** It has been updated to say

```
vector<BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel>* > > packing = new vector<BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> > >();
```

however, there is still the allocator error even with the adjusted templates.

> no matching function to call std::vector  , std::allocator  > > :: push_back(BinTreeNode > >&

```
BinTree<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >* Huffman::buildTree(const vector<HuffmanToken<Pixel>>& tokens) {

BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >* g1 = new BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >();
BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >* g2 = new BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >();
BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >* g3 = new BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >();

vector<HuffmanToken<Pixel> > packing ;

vector<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >::const_iterator it;

it = tokens.begin();

for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
  g1 -> setValue(tokens.at(i));
  packing.push_back(g1);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your vector is expecting `HuffmanToken<Pixel>` objects, but you're trying to `push_back` a `BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >*` pointer. Just make sure your vector has the right template type.

### Edit

Considering  your update, I decided to throw up all the code as it should be:

```
BinTree<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >* Huffman::buildTree(const vector<HuffmanToken<Pixel>>& tokens) {

    BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >* g1 = new BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >();
    BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >* g2 = new BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >();
    BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >* g3 = new BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >();

    vector<BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >*> packing ;

    vector<BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >*>::const_iterator it;

    it = tokens.begin();

    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
        g1 -> setValue(tokens.at(i));
        packing.push_back(g1);
    }
```

The only difference from the original code is that `vector<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >` is replaced with `vector<BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >*>` (that goes for the `vector` itself, as well as the iterator).

Comment: I'm still getting the following error  "request for member 'push_back' in 'packing', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >, std::allocator<BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> > > >*"

with this change to the vector 

    vector<BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> > >* packing = new vector<BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> > >();

Comment: Your vector shouldn't need to be a pointer. It should just store pointers. If I understand your code correctly, your vector should be declared as `vector<BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel>* > > packing;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your types don't match. You have a vector of `HuffmanToken<Pixel>`s and you're trying to push a `BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> > *` onto it.

Answer (score 1):

```
BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >* g1 = new BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >();
```

The type of `g1` is `BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >*` i.e., it is a pointer type. But `packing` is of type `vector<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >`. What the vector holds is objects but not pointers to objects.

Comment: *g1 is still not of type HuffmanToken<Pixel> but rather of type BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >.

Answer (score 1):

Your vector is of type `HuffmanToken<Pixel>` but you are trying to push type 
`BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >*` into it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are creating a vector that is supposed to hold items of type `HuffmanToken<Pixel>`. Instead of pushing items of that type into the vector, you try to push in a `BinTreeNode<HuffmanToken<Pixel> >*`.

And this cannot work.

What you probably wanted to push was the return value of *g1->getValue()* (if there is such a method at all...).